# Card layout in Java

Tags: java, swing

I have a JPanel (mainPanel) with `CardLayout` which contains 4 JPanels (childPanel).

Each `childPanel` contains:

- a JPopupMenu with 4 JMenuItems to switch between the childPanels (First,Last,Next,Previous)
- a label with the time when it got visible
- a `toggleButton` that shows/hides the label

I created [this working version](http://pastebin.com/aNkARuEZ) but I think it can be optimized.  Any advice is welcome.

```
public final class Prozor extends JFrame
{
    private static final Dimension SIZE = new Dimension(400, 300);

    private final JPanel panelButtoni = new JPanel();
    private JButton prvi;
    private JButton zadnji;
    private JButton sljedeci;
    private JButton prethodni;

    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    private JPanel panelCards = new JPanel(cardLayout);

    private JPopupMenu crveniMeni= new JPopupMenu();
    private JPanel crveniPanel= new JPanel();
    private JPopupMenu crveniKontekstni= new JPopupMenu();
    private JLabel crvenaLabelica = new JLabel();
    private JToggleButton crveniButton;

    private JPopupMenu plaviMeni= new JPopupMenu();
    private JPanel plaviPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPopupMenu plaviKontekstni = new JPopupMenu();
    private JLabel plavaLabelica = new JLabel();
    private JToggleButton plaviButton;

    private JPopupMenu zeleniMeni = new JPopupMenu();
    private JPanel zeleniPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPopupMenu zeleniKontekstni = new JPopupMenu();
    private JLabel zelenaLabelica = new JLabel();
    private JToggleButton zeleniButton;

    private JPopupMenu zutiMeni= new JPopupMenu();
    private JPanel zutiPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPopupMenu zutiKontekstni = new JPopupMenu();
    private JLabel zutaLabelica = new JLabel();
    private JToggleButton zutiButton;

    public Prozor(String title)
    {
        super(title);
        setPreferredSize(SIZE);
        setMinimumSize(SIZE);
        setMaximumSize(SIZE);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        kreirajbuttonAkcije();

        kreirajCrveniPanel();
        kreirajPlaviPanel();
        kreirajZeleniPanel();
        kreirajZutiPanel();

        this.add(panelCards);

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Prozor p = new Prozor("ime");
        p.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void kreirajCrveniPanel() {
        crveniPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        crveniButton = new JToggleButton("Prikazi vrijeme");
        crveniButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
            {
                if (crveniButton.isSelected()) {
                    crvenaLabelica.setText(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());
                    crvenaLabelica.setVisible(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    crvenaLabelica.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });

        JMenuItem jmPrvi = new JMenuItem("Prvi");
        jmPrvi.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                cardLayout.first(panelCards);
            }
        });
        JMenuItem jmZadnji = new JMenuItem("Zadnji");
        jmZadnji.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                cardLayout.last(panelCards);
            }
        });
        JMenuItem jmSljedeci = new JMenuItem("Sljedeći");
        jmSljedeci.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                cardLayout.next(panelCards);
            }
        });
        JMenuItem jmPrethodni = new JMenuItem("Prethodni");
        jmPrethodni.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                cardLayout.previous(panelCards);
            }
        });

        crveniPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
        {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
                if (me.isPopupTrigger()) {
                    crveniMeni.show(me.getComponent(), me.getX(), me.getY());
                }
            }


        });

        crveniMeni.add(jmPrvi);
        crveniMeni.add(jmZadnji);
        crveniMeni.add(jmPrethodni);
        crveniMeni.add(jmSljedeci);
        crveniPanel.add(crveniMeni);
        crveniPanel.add(crvenaLabelica);
        crveniPanel.add(crveniButton);
        panelCards.add(crveniPanel);
    }

    private void kreirajPlaviPanel() {
        plaviPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        plaviButton =new JToggleButton("Prikazi vrijeme");
        plaviButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (plaviButton.isSelected()) {
                    plavaLabelica.setText(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());
                    plavaLabelica.setVisible(true);
                }else{
                    plavaLabelica.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });

        JMenuItem jmPrvi = new JMenuItem("Prvi");
        jmPrvi.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                cardLayout.first(panelCards);
            }
        });
        JMenuItem jmZadnji = new JMenuItem("Zadnji");
        jmZadnji.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                cardLayout.last(panelCards);
            }
        });
        JMenuItem jmSljedeci = new JMenuItem("Sljedeći");
        jmSljedeci.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                cardLayout.next(panelCards);
            }
        });
        JMenuItem jmPrethodni = new JMenuItem("Prethodni");
        jmPrethodni.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                cardLayout.previous(panelCards);
            }
        });

        plaviPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
        {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
                if (me.isPopupTrigger()) {
                    plaviMeni.show(me.getComponent(), me.getX(), me.getY());
                }
            }


        });

        plaviMeni.add(jmPrvi);
        plaviMeni.add(jmZadnji);
        plaviMeni.add(jmPrethodni);
        plaviMeni.add(jmSljedeci);
        plaviPanel.add(plaviMeni);
        plaviPanel.add(plavaLabelica);
        plaviPanel.add(plaviButton);
        panelCards.add(plaviPanel);
    }

    private void kreirajZeleniPanel() {
        zeleniPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        zeleniButton=new JToggleButton("Prikazi vrijeme");
        zeleniButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (zeleniButton.isSelected()) {
                    zelenaLabelica.setText(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());
                    zelenaLabelica.setVisible(true);
                }else{
                    zelenaLabelica.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });

        JMenuItem jmPrvi = new JMenuItem("Prvi");
        jmPrvi.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                cardLayout.first(panelCards);
            }
        });
        JMenuItem jmZadnji = new JMenuItem("Zadnji");
        jmZadnji.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                cardLayout.last(panelCards);
            }
        });
        JMenuItem jmSljedeci = new JMenuItem("Sljedeći");
        jmSljedeci.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                cardLayout.next(panelCards);
            }
        });
        JMenuItem jmPrethodni = new JMenuItem("Prethodni");
        jmPrethodni.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                cardLayout.previous(panelCards);
            }
        });

        zeleniPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
        {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
                if (me.isPopupTrigger()) {
                    zeleniMeni.show(me.getComponent(), me.getX(), me.getY());
                }
            }


        });

        zeleniMeni.add(jmPrvi);
        zeleniMeni.add(jmZadnji);
        zeleniMeni.add(jmPrethodni);
        zeleniMeni.add(jmSljedeci);
        zeleniPanel.add(zeleniMeni);
        zeleniPanel.add(zelenaLabelica);
        zeleniPanel.add(zeleniButton);
        panelCards.add(zeleniPanel);
    }

    private void kreirajZutiPanel() {
        zutiPanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        zutiButton=new JToggleButton("Prikazi vrijeme");
        zutiButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (zutiButton.isSelected()) {
                    zutaLabelica.setText(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());
                    zutaLabelica.setVisible(true);
                }else{
                    zutaLabelica.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });

        JMenuItem jmPrvi = new JMenuItem("Prvi");
        jmPrvi.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                cardLayout.first(panelCards);
            }
        });
        JMenuItem jmZadnji = new JMenuItem("Zadnji");
        jmZadnji.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                cardLayout.last(panelCards);
            }
        });
        JMenuItem jmSljedeci = new JMenuItem("Sljedeći");
        jmSljedeci.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                cardLayout.next(panelCards);
            }
        });
        JMenuItem jmPrethodni = new JMenuItem("Prethodni");
        jmPrethodni.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                cardLayout.previous(panelCards);
            }
        });

        zutiPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
        {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
                if (me.isPopupTrigger()) {
                    zutiMeni.show(me.getComponent(), me.getX(), me.getY());
                }
            }


        });

        zutiMeni.add(jmPrvi);
        zutiMeni.add(jmZadnji);
        zutiMeni.add(jmPrethodni);
        zutiMeni.add(jmSljedeci);
        zutiPanel.add(zutiMeni);

        zutiPanel.add(zutaLabelica);
        zutiPanel.add(zutiButton);
        panelCards.add(zutiPanel);
    }

    private void kreirajbuttonAkcije() {
        prvi= new JButton("Prvi");
        prvi.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
            {
                cardLayout.first(panelCards);
            }
        });

        zadnji= new JButton("Zadnji");
        zadnji.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
            {
                cardLayout.last(panelCards);
            }
        });

        sljedeci= new JButton("Sljedeći");
        sljedeci.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
            {
                cardLayout.next(panelCards);
            }
        });

        prethodni= new JButton("Prethodni");
        prethodni.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
            {
                cardLayout.previous(panelCards);
            }
        });

        panelButtoni.add(prvi);
        panelButtoni.add(zadnji);
        panelButtoni.add(prethodni);
        panelButtoni.add(sljedeci);
        this.add(panelButtoni,BorderLayout.NORTH);

    }

}
```

Comment: kreirajCrveniPanel()
kreirajPlaviPanel() 
and so on are identical for the different panels, but i would like to make 1 function that handles all 4 since the code is the same

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer and have posted it in case someone has a similar problem:

I created a class that extends JPanel like this:

```
public class CardPanel extends JPanel{
    private JPopupMenu menu;
    private JLabel label;
    private JToggleButton button;
    private final CardLayout layout;
    private final JPanel parent;

    public CardPanel(CardLayout layout,Color color,JPanel parent)
    {
        super();
        this.layout = layout;
        this.parent=parent;
        setBackground(color);

        kreirajKontekstni();


    }

    private void kreirajKontekstni() {
        button =new JToggleButton("Prikazi vrijeme");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (button.isSelected()) {
                    label.setText(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());
                    label.setVisible(true);
                }else{
                    label.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });
        JMenuItem jmPrvi = new JMenuItem("Prvi");
        jmPrvi.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                layout.first(parent);
            }
        });
        JMenuItem jmZadnji = new JMenuItem("Zadnji");
        jmZadnji.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                layout.last(parent);
            }
        });
        JMenuItem jmSljedeci = new JMenuItem("Sljedeći");
        jmSljedeci.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                layout.next(parent);
            }
        });
        JMenuItem jmPrethodni = new JMenuItem("Prethodni");
        jmPrethodni.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                layout.previous(parent);
            }
        });

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
        {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
                if (me.isPopupTrigger()) {
                    menu.show(me.getComponent(), me.getX(), me.getY());
                }
            }


        });

        menu.add(jmPrvi);
        menu.add(jmZadnji);
        menu.add(jmPrethodni);
        menu.add(jmSljedeci);
        add(menu);
        add(label);
        add(button);
        parent.add(this);
    }

}
```

and changed the code in the main Window to:

```
public class SimpleProzor extends JFrame
{
    private static final Dimension SIZE = new Dimension(400, 300);

    private final JPanel panelButtoni = new JPanel();
    private JButton prvi;
    private JButton zadnji;
    private JButton sljedeci;
    private JButton prethodni;

    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    private JPanel panelCards = new JPanel(cardLayout);

    private CardPanel crveniPanel;
    private CardPanel plaviPanel;
    private CardPanel zeleniPanel;
    private CardPanel zutiPanel;

    public SimpleProzor(String title)
    {
        super(title);
        setPreferredSize(SIZE);
        setMinimumSize(SIZE);
        setMaximumSize(SIZE);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        kreirajbuttonAkcije();

        crveniPanel = new CardPanel(cardLayout, Color.RED, panelCards);
        plaviPanel = new CardPanel(cardLayout, Color.BLUE, panelCards);
        zeleniPanel = new CardPanel(cardLayout, Color.GREEN, panelCards);
        zutiPanel= new CardPanel(cardLayout, Color.YELLOW, panelCards);

        this.add(panelCards);

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Prozor p = new Prozor("ime");
        p.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void kreirajbuttonAkcije() {
        prvi= new JButton("Prvi");
        prvi.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
            {
                cardLayout.first(panelCards);
            }
        });

        zadnji= new JButton("Zadnji");
        zadnji.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
            {
                cardLayout.last(panelCards);
            }
        });

        sljedeci= new JButton("Sljedeći");
        sljedeci.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
            {
                cardLayout.next(panelCards);
            }
        });

        prethodni= new JButton("Prethodni");
        prethodni.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
            {
                cardLayout.previous(panelCards);
            }
        });

        panelButtoni.add(prvi);
        panelButtoni.add(zadnji);
        panelButtoni.add(prethodni);
        panelButtoni.add(sljedeci);
        this.add(panelButtoni,BorderLayout.NORTH);   
    }   
}
```